# Determine currently selected slide using PowerPoint API

Tags: office-js

I am creating a PowerPoint addin using the JS-based [Office Add-ins platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?view=excel-js-preview).

As demonstrated by `getSelectedSlideIndex()` from [this sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/powerpoint/preview-apis/tags.yaml), it is easy to determine the currently selected slide. Using [`Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-preview#getSelectedDataAsync_coercionType__options__callback_) with `Office.CoercionType.SlideRange`.

Having a slide it is also possible to obtain all contained shapes. For example:

```
const slide = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0);
const shape = slide.shapes.getItemAt(0);
```

Now I am looking for a way to determine which the currently selected shape is. <sup>(That is, the shape that the user clicked on last. The shape that would be removed when pressing `DEL`. Etc.)</sup> `getSelectedDataAsync()` has no appropriate coercion type parameter. Is there another method I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, getting selected shape is not yet supported. If you'd like to request for this feature, please post it to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

A new [PowerPoint JavaScript preview APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/powerpoint/powerpoint-preview-apis?view=common-js-preview) was released in June 2022 which offers [getSelectedShapes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.presentation?view=powerpoint-js-preview#powerpoint-powerpoint-presentation-getselectedshapes-member(1)). Since it is a beta version it cannot be used yet for official release but that should change in the near future. I hope...

Comment: Any news on this ? getSelectedShapes doesn't seems supported yet right ?